# PropertyChanged is null while drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

There might be some solution out there but so far I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution to this. Any help would be appreciated. Currently I have a dialog box to which I upload files either by clicking the button or by dragging and dropping the files from the file explorer. The dialog box contains a `DataGrid` to which is bound an `ObservableCollection<FileDetails>`. An event handler for `PropertyChanged` has been attached as well to this property. When I add a file through button click the PropertyChanged event is fired and the UI is updated with the added file. However, when I drag and drop the file to the dataGrid the PropertyChanged handler is null.

Below is my ViewModel:

```
public class FileUploadVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private static ObservableCollection<FileDetails> m_DialogFiles;
    public ObservableCollection<FileDetails> DialogFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return m_DialogFiles ?? new ObservableCollection<FileDetails>();
        }
        set
        {
            m_DialogFiles = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DialogFiles));
        }
    }

    public ICommand FileUpload
    {
        get
        {
            return new SimpleCommand(AddFiles);
        }
    }

    private void AddFiles(object obj)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.Multiselect = true;
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            m_fileList = openFile.FileNames.ToList();
            GetFileWithIcon();
        }
        DialogFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileDetails>(dgFiles);
    }
}
```

Below is a part of my XAML code

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DialogFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HeadersVisibility="None" AllowDrop="True" Drop="dataGrid1_Drop">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding FileIcon}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FileName}" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="Delete">
                            <Image Source="/AssemblyName;component/Resources/delete_icon.png" Height="15" Width="20"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Width="60" Margin="10" Command="{Binding Path=FileUpload}">Add Files</Button>
        <Button Width="60" Margin="10">Upload</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this is the CodeBehind

```
public partial class FileDialog : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<FileDetails> m_fileDialog;
    public FileDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = FileUpload; 
    }  

    public FileUploadVM FileUpload
    {
        get
        {
            return new FileUploadVM();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileDetails> DialogFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return m_fileDialog ?? FileUpload.DialogFiles;
        }
    }

    private void dataGrid1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] droppedFiles = null;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            droppedFiles = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
        }
        if ((null == droppedFiles) || (!droppedFiles.Any()))
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var item in droppedFiles)
        {
            FileUploadVM.m_fileList.Add(item);
        }            
        FileUpload.GetFileWithIcon();
        FileUpload.DialogFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileDetails>(FileUploadVM.dgFiles);
        FileUploadVM.m_fileList.Clear();
    }
}
```

As mentioned above clicking on AddFiles works fine, but dragging and dropping does not fire PropertyChanged in spite of DialogFiles having values within.

Comment: property `FileUpload` creates a new intance *on each call*. you work with multiple instances instead of 1

Comment: Please see my answer below, you do not need to fire off NotifyChange on that property, because it is an ObservableCollection. When adding/removing/clearing that collection, it will automatically notify the View that the collection has changed, so you should not have to worry about that :)

Comment: @ASh Thank you!! Can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akshatha

I've identified a few issues with your solution:

**Problem 1** - You set your DataContext (ViewModel) incorrectly, if you look at the following code:

```
public FileUploadVM FileUpload {
    get {
        return new FileUploadVM();
    }
}
```

The above code creates a new instance of your ViewModel every time you request the ViewModel object. This means that whenever you call this object:

```
FileUploadVM.m_fileList.Clear();
```

it will create a new object, and will break your reference to your DataContext (View -> ViewModel).

**EDIT**
you can fix this by creating a normal property to retrieve the ViewModel object and use this instance every time you need to access your ViewModel:

```
private FileUploadVM fileUploadVM = new FileUploadVM();

public FileUploadVM FileUploadVM {
    get { return this.fileUploadVM; }
    set {
        if (this.fileUploadVM != value) {
            this.fileUploadVM = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem 2**: You destroy your reference when you re-initialize your collection of DialogFiles:

```
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileDetails>(FileUploadVM.dgFiles);
```

Whenever you create a new Instance of this object, your view will need to be notified that there is a new collection that needs to be bound to and not to use the 'old' collection which you are not using anymore. One way to make sure you *always* use the right instance of the collection is to make it read-only:

```
public ObservableCollection<FileDetails> DialogFiles {
    get {
        return m_DialogFiles;
    }
}
```

and only adding/clearing from *that* single instance of the collection, so instead of doing this:

```
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileDetails>(FileUploadVM.dgFiles);
```

The read-only proeprty will not allow you to do this, and rather use this to modify your collection:

```
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles.Add(new FileDetails("Your FileName"));
```

and if you should dlete/clear an item from the collection, you can simply use

```
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles.Clear();
// OR
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles.Remove(myFileDetailsItem); 
// OR
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles.RemoveAt(index);
```

**To summarize**, your problem was that you created a new instance of your DialogFiles collection when hitting the Drop method:

```
FileUploadVM.DialogFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileDetails>(FileUploadVM.dgFiles);
```

and you should rather just add to that collection than re-declaring the instance:

```
foreach(var file in FileUploadVM.dgFiles) {
    FileUploadVM.DialogFiles.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your fix for the Problem 1 did help me and worked there after. However, as per your comment if the INotifyPropertyChanged is removed it does not update the UI. Also, I have tried adding the items to the collection but for some unknown reason even after adding the item my collection count remains 0. Which is why I had to take this route. And it works!!

Comment: No problem, glad to have been able to help out. When developing WPF apps using the MVVM pattern, its almost mandatory to use  [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check out your application 'skeleton' in runtime. It saved me LOTS of headaches identifying why the DataContext was not working correctly, why the ItemsSource was not updating, or why the application behaved strange in general.